# Calling string from another method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with calling a string from another method from the same script. I'm not sure if this is possible with C#
Sorry I'm new to C# but I used to do this in Objective-C so maybe its possible here?

So, the below code is the method I'm trying to use that string into.
This method checked if a message is passed in the game and execute the code.

```
void HandleMessage(string message, string metadata)
{

    if (message == "UnlockName")
    {

    }
}
```

This is the method that contains the string needed (txt)

```
    void OutputText( string txt ) {
    //string firstName = lastLoadedLevel.contact.name.Split(new char[] { ' ' })[0];
    //txt = txt.Replace("C:", firstName + ":");

    txt = txt.Replace("D:", "D's name:");

    txt = txt.Replace("[name]", PlayerPrefs.GetString("name"));

    chat.AddText( txt, delegate {
        options.gameObject.SetActive( true );
    } );
}
```

Right now it contains (txt.Replace) which happens automaticlly throughout the text output.
I want to do the same in (void HandleMessage) to only do the replace code when the message "UnlockName" is passed.
The 2 commented lines here are what I need to use but I don't know how to use them in the first method.

Any help would be great :)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: We need a broader context here to understand. This methods belong to same class or seperate ones? What method calls OutputText first?

Comment: Where does `HandleMessage` get called?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
string HandleMessage(string message, string txt)
{
    if (message == "UnlockName")
    {
        string firstName = lastLoadedLevel.contact.name.Split(new char[] { ' ' })[0];
        return txt.Replace("C:", firstName + ":");
    }
}

void OutputText(string txt, string message) 
{
    txt = HandleMessage(message, txt);
    txt = txt.Replace("D:", "D's name:");
    txt = txt.Replace("[name]", PlayerPrefs.GetString("name"));
    chat.AddText(txt, delegate 
        {
            options.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        });
}
```

Might need some tweaking, I made some guesses on how you might be using things.

If nothing else, it should give you the concept of one way to pass strings in and back out of a method. You could also keep the void signature and pass in the string to be manipulated as a ref parameter.